# Insert data to mysql using table thread in html

Tags: php, html

I have a trouble about inserting the data inside of a table in html..

this my HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <colgroup>
        <col span="2" class="c2">
        <col>
        <col class="c1">
    </colgroup>
    <thread>
        <tr style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;margin: 50px;">
            <th >Employee ID</th>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Time Start</th>
            <th>Time End</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="insertionPoint" style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;margin: 50px;">
      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is what look like:

```
Employee ID  Fullname     Time Start        Time End            Purpose
212          Beta Tester  03/15/2021 15:35  03/15/2021  17:35   hello
```

my submit code html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Insert" name="submit" onclick="addRow('t1')" />
          
   <?php
   $empid = $var_value = $_SESSION['username'];
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_username = "****";
    $mysql_password = "***";
    $mysql_database = "***";
    $conn= mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
// Check connection
   
    
    if($_POST[submit])
    {
        
     foreach ($_POST['Employee ID'] as $key => $value) 
        {
            $empid = $_POST["Employee ID"][$key];
            $dstart = $_POST["Time Start"][$key];
            $dend = $_POST["Time End"][$key];
            $purpose = $_POST["Purpose"][$key];
          

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `HR_OT_Items` (`Employee_ID`, `Date_Start`, `Date_end`, `Purpose`)values('$empid','$dstart','$dend','$purpose')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 
    echo '<script>alert("Successfully Saved!")</script>'; 
 
    }
    else{
 
     echo 'Connection Failed';
 
    }
     mysqli_close($conn);
            
        }

    }   
?>
```

after the submit nothing happens. No data in MySQL. Can someone encounter this?

**EDIT**
The essential elements from the HTML form with clutter removed

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="empid" id="empid" onchange="employees">
        <option value="" >--Select--</option>
        <?php
            if (! empty($empids)) {
                foreach ($empids as $empid) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $empid;?>">
            <?php echo $empid;?>
        </option>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?> 
    </select>
            
    <select name="employees" id="employees" onchange="empid">
        <option value="" >--Select--</option>
        <?php
            if (! empty($fnames)) {
                foreach ($fnames as $fname) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fname;?>"> 
            <?php echo $fname;?>
        </option>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?> 
    </select>

    <input type="datetime-local" id="myTime" />
    
    <select name="hours" id="hours">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="11">11</option>
       <option value="12">12</option>
       <option value="13">13</option>
       <option value="14">14</option>
       <option value="15">15</option>
       <option value="16">16</option>
       <option value="17">17</option>
       <option value="18">18</option>
       <option value="19">19</option>
       <option value="20">20</option>
       <option value="21">21</option>
       <option value="22">22</option>
       <option value="23">23</option>
       <option value="24">24</option>
       <option value="25">25</option>
       <option value="26">26</option>
       <option value="27">27</option>
       <option value="28">28</option>
       <option value="29">29</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>

    
    <select name="mins" id="mins">
       <option value="0">0</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="button" onClick="ClearDate()" value="Clear">
    
    <textarea name="textarea" id="purpose" style="width:100%;height:170px;"></textarea>
    
    <input type="button" onClick="insertData()" value="Add entry">
    
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="submit" onclick="addRow('t1')" />
</form>
```

Supporting Javascript functions:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var myTime = document.getElementById("myTime");
    myTime.value = new Date(myTime);
   
   
    function insertData() {
        var str = myTime.value;    
        var e = document.getElementById("hours");
        var d = document.getElementById("mins");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var strUser1 = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;



        var a = parseInt(strUser);
        var c = parseInt(strUser1);

        var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
        var empname = document.getElementById("employees").value;

        var start =  new Date(str);
        var end = new Date(str);

        end.setHours(end.getHours() + a);
        end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + c);



        var dateOptions = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
        var timeOptions = { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };

        var starting = start.toLocaleString('en', dateOptions) + ' ' +  start.toLocaleString('en', timeOptions);

        var ending = end.toLocaleString('en', dateOptions) + ' ' +  end.toLocaleString('en', timeOptions);



        var purpose = document.getElementById("purpose").value;
        document.getElementById("insertionPoint").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + empid + "</td><td>" + empname + "</td><td>" + starting + "</td><td>" + ending +  "</td><td>" + purpose + "</td></tr>";

        // The below part is to clear the values after the entry is added.

        document.getElementById("empid").value = "";
        document.getElementById("employees").value = "";
        document.getElementById("myTime").value = "";
        document.getElementById("hours").value = "0";
        document.getElementById("mins").value = "0";
        document.getElementById("purpose").value = "";
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    function ClearData() {
        document.getElementById("empid").value = "";
        document.getElementById("employees").value = "";
        document.getElementById("myTime").value = "";
        document.getElementById("hours").value = "0";
        document.getElementById("mins").value = "0";
        document.getElementById("purpose").value = "";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Can you add the HTML Form that you are using? From what you have shown it seems like a basic misunderstanding of tables ~ tables in the database and HTML table elements in the page

Comment: yes this is the error PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant submit - assumed 'submit'

Comment: Please ad all necessary code to reproduce the error

Comment: what kind of html form sir? sorry i'm only 2 weeks old newbie

Comment: where are you hoping to get `$_POST["Employee ID"]` etc from? Are you using AJAX or a regular form?

Comment: oh $empid = $_POST["Employee ID"][$key]; is like from  <th >Employee ID</th> i am using regular form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229924/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-kejie-nandaru).

Comment: In the PHP you refer to `$_POST['Employee ID']` - yet the closest FORM element name is `empid` or possibly `employees` - however you DO have a table column header with `Employee ID` as content. This does seem to suggest a basic misunderstanding of how this process works &/or what the above code works.

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can figure your code is missing a form to actually `ADD` the data. Your javascript function ( after some tweaks ) will take the values from the first form and build a new HTML table row but I think this is where the first misunderstanding occurs because the data added to the HTML table will simply be textual data and will not appear in any POST submission as it was. To accomplish the adding of data the newly generated HTML table rows should have data within form elements (unless this entire process is to be done with AJAX ) - so, with that in mind, I have put together a working demo ( stripped down HTML ) to hopefully replicate your situation and show how you ***might*** do this. If this is not what you intended then I did not grasp properly what I saw in the HTML nor the question.

```
<?PHP
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            table,td{border:1px solid gray}
            td,th{padding:0.5rem;}
            th{background:gray;color:white;}
            table td input[type='text']{border:none;}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
            
                // the input element needs the date formatted in a particular manner
                // this was a quick way to do that
                var myTime = document.getElementById("myTime");
                    myTime.value = ( new Date() ).toISOString().replace(/\Z/gi,'');
               
               
                function insertData(e){
                    e.preventDefault()
                    
                    var str = myTime.value;    
                    var e = document.getElementById("hours");
                    var d = document.getElementById("mins");
                    
                    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                    var strUser1 = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
                    
                    var a = parseInt(strUser);
                    var c = parseInt(strUser1);
        
                    var empid = document.getElementById("empid").value;
                    var empname = document.getElementById("employees").value;
        
                    var start = new Date(str);
                    var end = new Date(str);
                        end.setHours(end.getHours() + a);
                        end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + c);
        
                    var dateOptions = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
                    var timeOptions = { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' };
        
                    var starting = start.toLocaleString('en', dateOptions) + ' ' +  start.toLocaleString('en', timeOptions);
                    var ending = end.toLocaleString('en', dateOptions) + ' ' +  end.toLocaleString('en', timeOptions);
                    
                    /*
                        Each new row will have `input` elements in each cell
                        - these input elements are used to actually ADD the
                        data when the form is submitted.
                    */
                    var purpose = document.getElementById("purpose").value;
                    document.getElementById("insertionPoint").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='empid[]' value='" + empid + "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='name[]' value='" + empname + "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='time_start[]' value='" + starting + "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='time_end[]' value='" + ending +  "' /></td><td><input type='text' name='purpose[]' value='" + purpose + "' /></td></tr>";

                    document.getElementById("empid").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("employees").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("myTime").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("hours").value = "0";
                    document.getElementById("mins").value = "0";
                    document.getElementById("purpose").value = "";  
                    
                    
                    myTime.value = ( new Date() ).toISOString().replace(/\Z/gi,'');
                }
                
                function addRow(e){
                    document.forms.add.submit()
                }
                
                function ClearData(e){
                    e.preventDefault()
                    document.getElementById("empid").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("employees").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("myTime").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("hours").value = "0";
                    document.getElementById("mins").value = "0";
                    document.getElementById("purpose").value = "";                  
                }
               
               
               
                document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="insertdata"]').addEventListener('click',insertData)
                document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][name="addrow"]').addEventListener('click',addRow)
                document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="cleardate"]').addEventListener('click',ClearData)
            })

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            
            # DUMMY DATA
            $empids=array(
                123456,78915423,4234645,64564573,2345756,23428754
            );
            $fnames=array(
                'douglas','horatio','napoleon','bill','pocahontas','geronimo'
            );
        
        ?>
        
        
        <form method='POST'>
            <select name='empid' id='empid' onchange='employees'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>--Select--
                <?php
                    if( !empty( $empids ) ) {
                        foreach( $empids as $empid ) {
                ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $empid;?>'>
                    <?php echo $empid;?>
                
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?> 
            </select>
                    
            <select name='employees' id='employees' onchange='empid'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>--Select--
                <?php
                    if( !empty( $fnames ) ) {
                        foreach( $fnames as $fname ) {
                ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $fname;?>'> 
                    <?php echo $fname;?>
                
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?> 
            </select>

            <input type='datetime-local' id='myTime' />
            
            <select name='hours' id='hours'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>--Select--
                <option value='0'>0
                <option value='1'>1
                <option value='2'>2
                <option value='3'>3
                <option value='4'>4
                <option value='5'>5
                <option value='6'>6
                <option value='7'>7
                <option value='8'>8
                <option value='9'>9
                <option value='10'>10
                <option value='11'>11
                <option value='12'>12
                <option value='13'>13
                <option value='14'>14
                <option value='15'>15
                <option value='16'>16
                <option value='17'>17
                <option value='18'>18
                <option value='19'>19
                <option value='20'>20
                <option value='21'>21
                <option value='22'>22
                <option value='23'>23
                <option value='24'>24
                <option value='25'>25
                <option value='26'>26
                <option value='27'>27
                <option value='28'>28
                <option value='29'>29
                <option value='30'>30
            </select>

            
            <select name='mins' id='mins'>
                <option selected hidden disabled>--Select--
                <option value='0'>0
                <option value='30'>30
            </select>
            
            <input type='button' value='Clear' name='cleardate' />
            <textarea name='textarea' id='purpose' style='width:100%;height:170px;'></textarea>
            
            <input type='button' value='Add entry' name='insertdata' />
            <input type='submit' value='Insert' name='addrow' form='add' /><!-- assigned to other form that actually submits the data -->
        </form>
    
    
    
        <form id='add' method='post'>
           <table id='t1'>
              <colgroup>
                 <col span='2' class='c2'>
                 <col>
                 <col class='c1'>
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                 <tr style='text-align: center; font-size: 16px;margin: 50px;'>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Fullname</th>
                    <th>Time Start</th>
                    <th>Time End</th>
                    <th>Purpose</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id='insertionPoint' style='text-align: center; font-size: 13px;margin: 50px;'><!-- dynamic content here --></tbody>
           </table>
        </form>
        
        
        <?php
        
            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root';
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
            $dbname =   'xxx';
            
            try{
                mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
                $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                
                if( isset( 
                    $_POST['empid'],
                    $_POST['time_start'],
                    $_POST['time_end'],
                    $_POST['purpose']
                )){
                    
                    $sql='INSERT INTO `hr_ot_items` ( `employee_id`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `purpose` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
                    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $empid, $start, $end, $purpose );
                    
                    foreach( $_POST['empid'] as $i => $empid ){
                        $start=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $_POST['time_start'][$i] ) );
                        $end=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $_POST['time_end'][$i] ) );
                        $purpose=$_POST['purpose'][$i];
                        
                        $res=$stmt->execute();
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            }
        ?>      
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this sir and I will update you

Answer (score 0):

You must include array key with quotes:

```
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
```

This is your first mistake but perhaps fixing this can solve the main problem too. otherwise, we need your database table structur too.